# Propel and related data using FOSUserbundle

Tags: symfony, join, foreign-keys, propel, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOSUserBundle and I've created a Message table with two columns, that are relating to the User from FOSUserBundle.

I want to get messages and information about the author using one query.

Following schema.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<database name="default" namespace="Acme\StoreBundle\Model" defaultIdMethod="native">

<table name="message">
    <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" />
    <column name="title" type="varchar" size="64" required="true" defaultValue="(untitled)"/>
    <column name="content" type="longvarchar" />
    <column name="author_id" type="integer" required="true" />
        <foreign-key foreignTable="fos_user">
            <reference local="author_id" foreign="id" />
        </foreign-key>
    <column name="recipient_id" type="integer" required="true" />
        <foreign-key foreignTable="fos_user">
            <reference local="recipient_id" foreign="id" />
        </foreign-key>
</table>
</database>
```

I was trying many options, with no result.

When I try, what seems to be logical:

```
$messages = MessageQuery::create()
            ->join('Message.Authorid')
            ->findByRecipientId(1);
```

I get an error: "Unknown table or alias Message"

With:

```
->join('Authorid')
```

Error: "Unknown relation Authorid on the Acme\StoreBundle\Model\Message table"

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found it out.

The schema for both author and recipient has to look like:

```
...
<column name="author_id" type="integer" required="true" />
    <foreign-key foreignTable="fos_user" phpName="Author">
        <reference local="author_id" foreign="id" />
    </foreign-key>

<column name="recipient_id" type="integer" required="true" />
    <foreign-key foreignTable="fos_user" phpName="Recipient">
        <reference local="recipient_id" foreign="id" />
    </foreign-key>
...
```

The important part is the phpName.

Now the controller. And here is something weird that happens, but it doesn't disturb.

```
$messages = MessageQuery::create()
    ->find();

return $this->render('AcmeStoreBundle:Message:index.html.twig',
        array('messages' => $messages)
    );
```

And after this easy code, I have access to everything from twig.

At this point I'd like to show an example:

When the controller looks like above, then

```
# AcmeStoreBundle:Message:index.html.twig

messages
```

Shows every field of the message table like:

```
Acme\StoreBundle\Model\Message_0: Id: 1 CreatedAt: !!php/object:O:8:"DateTime":3:    {s:4:"date";s:19:"2013-03-20 13:00:00";s:13:"timezone_type";i:3;s:8:"timezone";s:12:"Europe/Paris";} Title: (untitled) Content: 'test content' AuthorId: 1 RecipientId: 2 Acme\StoreBundle\Model\Message_1: Id: 2 CreatedAt: !!php/object:O:8:"DateTime":3:{s:4:"date";s:19:"2013-03-20 13:15:22";s:13:"timezone_type";i:3;s:8:"timezone";s:12:"Europe/Paris";} Title: (untitled2) Content: 'bla bla content 2' AuthorId: 2 RecipientId: 1
```

As you can see, there is nothing about the relationship with author or recipient, but when I call message.author.username, or message.recipient.username (in the for loop of messages) I'm getting this. And this is what I actually expected.

And now when the controller looks like:

```
$messages = MessageQuery::create()
        ->joinWith('Author')
        ->find();

return $this->render('AcmeStoreBundle:Message:index.html.twig',
        array('messages' => $messages)
    );
```

messages (in twig) throws all the fields like above, and an author object (called author, not user, because of phpName from the schema).

Thank you guys for reading my question and many thx for participation.

Answer (score 1):

The `join` method takes the relation using tables or phpName aliases, not the fields. So you probably want:

```
->join("Message.Author")
```

Or, as your foreign key suggests, maybe this?

```
->join("Message.FosUser")
```

**UPDATE**

With two FK references to the same table, you will want to use the `phpName` and `refPhpName` attributes of the foreign-key tag:

```
<table name="message">
  ...
  <foreign-key foreignTable="fos_user" phpName="Author" refPhpName="AuthoredMessage">
    <reference local="author_id" foreign="id" />
  </foreign-key>
  <foreign-key foreignTable="fos_user" phpName="Recipient" refPhpName="ReceivedMessage">
    <reference local="recipient_id" foreign="id" />
  </foreign-key>
</table>
```

Then you could try using `->join('Message.Author')` or `->join('Message.Recipient')`

See the [documentation of the foreign-key element](http://propelorm.org/reference/schema.html#foreign-key-element).

Comment: Unknown table or alias Message
500 Internal Server Error - PropelException

In both cases. ;/

Comment: I think you need to find out what the name of that other class is... if it's `User` then the part after the dot (`.`) should be `User`. I think you get the point. Anyway, need to know what Propel thinks the connected class is. Oh! But I see that you have two FK references to the same table... could be problematic. See my update.